# executing a simple go .exe in a dockerfile

Tags: docker, go

I have the following dockerfile and everything works fine except for running the .exe

```
FROM golang:latest

# Set the Current Working Directory inside the container
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/github.com/user/goserver

# Copy everything from the current directory to the PWD (Present Working Directory) inside the container
COPY . .

# Download all the dependencies
RUN go get -d -v ./...

# Install the package
RUN GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o goserver .

# This container exposes port 8080 to the outside world
EXPOSE 8080

# Run the executable
CMD ./goserver
```

The problem is that it does not execute './goserver'.  I need to manually go into the container and then execute it.  Any idea what could be going wrong here ?

Comment: can you also include how do you create the container?

Comment: its
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 goserver /bin/bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way you are running the container.

By running the container with the following:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 goserver /bin/bash
```

you are overriding the command defined with `CMD` in `Dockerfile` to `bin/bash` command.

You can start the container in detached mode by running it as:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 goserver
```

Further, if you want to later `exec` into the container then you can use the `docker exec` command.

Comment: I would suggest to read the answers to the question [difference between `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile)